# sbt publish produces jar with too many folders in the path => unresolved dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to test a project, so I did `sbt publish-local` (here's the project's build file: [build.sbt](https://github.com/oysterbooks/scavro/blob/master/build.sbt)).

I expected that a jar be produced with the path:

```
/Users/julianpeeters/.ivy2/local/com.oysterbooks/scavro_2.10/0.9.0/jars
```

But instead I got:

```
/Users/julianpeeters/.ivy2/local/com.oysterbooks/scavro/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.9.0/jars
```

1) How come the two extra directories `scala_2.10` and `sbt_0.13` were generated?

2) How can I reference the jar as a sbt `libraryDependency`? For example, `"com.oysterbooks" % "scavro" % "0.9.0"` wont work.

Currently my workaround is moving the jar into the `scavro` directory manually after publishing.

Thanks

Comment: what version of `SBT`?

Comment: for part #2, you need to either include the `_2.10` suffix or change to using a `%%` (see: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html#using-cross-built-libraries)

Comment: Thanks for the response. `SBT` version is `0.13.8` (for the project being published, and the test project, though my launcher is `0.13.6`)

Comment: for part #2, those methods would work for my expected path, but they don't work my actual path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deliberate Scala/SBT-version folders you are seeing in the published ivy directory is a result of the `sbtPlugin := true` command.

Comment: Which means that `Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.oysterbooks" % "scavro" % "0.9.0", "0.13", "2.10")` is how I should represent it as a dependency. Thank you very much.